# How can I optimize OpenCV's Canny edge detection for low resolution/blurry footage

Tags: opencv

I have low resolution blurry grayscale images and running canny edge detection against it does not produce any results (black image). Here an example of the images :

[image: blurry image]

Is there an (relative easy/fast) way to either prepare the images for canny or use any other OpenCV algorithm that performs better with blurry images ?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Try [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33685413/2571705).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a wider Gaussian filter. And the thresholds need to be set lower. If you use my routine from the binary image library, it's available in source, so you can see the effects of adjusting the parameters. 
[Canny source](https://github.com/MalcolmMcLean/binaryimagelibrary/blob/master/canny.c)

Comment: Thanks. I have never run opencv as c code. Always via the python bindings. How can I use your c code from within python or standalone. Sorry for this newbie question...and thanks for your help.

Comment: I don't know how to wider the Gaussian in OpenCV, but you can simply reduce the thresholds as Malcolm McLean said. I got such result(https://postimg.org/image/ykc7lwlyz/) with edges = cv2.Canny(img,10,30).

Comment: Awesome !! Thanks. For some reason I made an error when I tested the values and it did not give me and good resuts. Now I restarted and your values work perfectly. Thanks so much !!